# Output of application based on Eclipse on Windows command line only visible when piped (not directly in cmd)

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, cmd, stdout

We have a Java application based on Eclipse (main class implements `IApplication`) that is started from the Windows command line.  Its output on `System.out` is not visible/printed into the command window from which it is started.  Nevertheless, when piping the output to `more`, the output is fine. How come?

For example, consider `helloworld.exe`.  When running `C:\>helloworld.exe` in a command window, the application simply returns.  But when running `C:\>helloworld.exe | more`, the screen shows

> C:>helloworld.exe | more
>
> hello world
>
> C:>

On linux, the output is fine.  How to see the output on Windows, too?

Some reqested information:

- The application is quite large.  And I probably cannot cut it down.  The output are simple calls to `System.out.prinln("xxx");`
- Java version `1.8.0_60`, Eclipse `3.6.2`
- Using `>std.txt 2>err.txt` shows that output is indeed on stdout.
- Line endings are CR/LF

the `.ini` file is as follows

```
--launcher.suppressErrors
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx4096m
-Djava.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
-Djava.library.path=plugins
```

Maybe [this issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=146807) is related?

Comment: Show us the part of code that creates the output. Do you have a helloworld._ini_ alongside your executable ? Which java version ? Which eclipse version ?

Comment: `more` might be more lenient concerning line endings. Maybe you have just `\r` or `\n`. Use `... >out.txt 2>err.txt` to check line endings with a programmer's editor like NotePad++. Maybe `flush()` may be needed as no println done,

Comment: I once had a similar problem with a readymade application based on Eclipse 3.x. I was only able to see the output of Eclipse and the underlying plugins when I made Eclipse use java.exe instead of javaw.exe. But this had the drawback of always showing an additional console window when calling the program from an icon. In addition to this we created a Java based wrapper application (kinda overkill ;-)) that calls eclipse and explicitly sets a incoming and outgoing stream in order to read stdout and stderr output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch Eclipse RCP based applications using equinox launcher as shown below:

```
java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
```

Of course you have to find the correct version of equinox launcher you are using in your RCP Application.

This way you would see the console logs.

You can read more about it here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Starting_Eclipse_Commandline_With_Equinox_Launcher

EDIT: The reason you don't get console logs when eclipse.exe based launcher is used is because eclipse.exe on Windows spawns a separate process which brings up another command prompt window.

Answer (score 5):

If your application is somehow started via `eclipse.exe` (has no console attached to it) change the call to use the `eclipsec.exe` (has a console attached to it, note the `c` in the application name).

Comment: Best answer!!! Thanks a lot! Been using eclipse for 13 years, and i didn't knew about the "eclipsec" alternative!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a framework to handle your logs like [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)

This is much more portable and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks. But it's an existing application and our log framework won't change.  And because piping the output works, I somehow suspect a Windows issue

Answer (score 0):

In your example it seems that you have created an exe from your java code. My guess is that the packager you used to create the exe made some changes to the output target because it is a wrapper for your java program.
Try creating a jar instead and try executing it by java -jar helloworld.jar.

Comment: No, this is the approach where you have the Eclipse framework bootstrap a complete application. You copy eclipse.exe and configure it to start some of your code as an application

Answer (score 0):

Is the string going to stderr in place of stdout? (or the other way around depending on your expected behaviour).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110930

Comment: Shouldn't both, stdour and stderr, be visible on the console? And why then is the ouptut visible when piped? But I'll check